# How can I connect smart lightbulbs to a public Wi-Fi network that requires a web page to be opened to enter credentials for use?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, authentication

I'm posting this question here as I've been stuck with this issue for a while now, without finding any good solution...

I'm looking to connect my smart lightbulbs and other connected equipment in my new flat. However, here's the issue: It is a public network. In order to connect to the internet, a webpage needs to be opened to enter some credentials I have.

However, with the intelligent equipment, I have absolutely no way of getting on this webpage to get authenticated and, therefore, access the internet.

I've been having this issue for a few days now, and I have no clue how to solve it. The only "viable" solution I've thought of and, succeeded, is to use the 'Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter'. It seems like it is emulating my own connection, allowing other devices to connect on my computer's network, therefore not needing any portal to be opened...

Considering I would like to avoid leaving my computer turned on 24/7, I'm looking for another solution.

FWIW, I've looked into MAC-spoofing techniques in order to act like another connected device on the network, but I would like to use a more 'legal' technique, even if I have to buy a little piece of hardware.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you are describing an [XY problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) and thus [your original title](https://superuser.com/posts/1742972/revisions) is misleading to you and others. Thus my rewording of the title. That said, the best solution might be to buy your own Wi-Fi router that you can then use to connect to the public Wi-Fi. In that way the connection to the public Wi-Fi would be permanent and then you would connect to the Wi-Fi router “he normal way” and thus smart bulbs could connect to that Wi-Fi router as well.

Comment: Hello @Giacomo1968 ! Thanks for your help. Sorry for this, I'm not used to posting on forums :) - Is there any way for me to set up a router to 'login' on the webpage, therefore allowing everyone connecting on it to avoid going through the portal? Seems like I can't find anything on the internet helping me do such a thing - sorry for being such a newbie!

Comment: My comment was about the structure of your question and the communication issues it had. As for how to do what I describe? I would leave that for others to answer. I cannot answer; it was just an idea.

Comment: Can you put a router in front of the public network and then connect your devices to that?

Comment: Hello @John :) - Is this doable, yes, probably. The problem is that I am not sure how I could allow one single auth for all equipment connected on the AP :( I am worried it would simply act like any repeater, and just requires the portal of the host to be opened :(

Comment: Take a new router, connect the WAN port to the public network. Then you have your own router for your own equipment.

Comment: But wouldn't this just act as a repeater, which would require every device connected to my own router to authenticate using the web portal ? (if if this works as you said, how could I possibly log my own router on the web portal?) @John

Comment: I don't know your equipment but I hook devices up to a router in my own network.  Should work. Also the way I suggested it is just a router and not a repeater (assuming you have Ethernet access in your flat) . If you are on a public network with other flats that is highly insecure.

Comment: I'm just scared of the web portal to be honest :/ If I buy a router and it ends up just being a repeater, it would just be useless :( - The whole point is to get around the web portal by using an existing device being already logged in :( (And yes, I do have Ethernet access)

Comment: @John “Take a new router, connect the WAN port to the public network. Then you have your own router for your own equipment.” Please read the question again: The public internet the original poster is using is Wi-Fi. No Ethernet connection in place. Maybe a repeater with an Ethernet port to a router? I don’t have enough experience to suggest hardware but something that could connect to Wi-Fi as a WAN and then just route specific IP addresses connected to that router is the way to go.

Comment: OP says they have Ethernet

Comment: @John The only mentions of “Ethernet” come from your comments and my comment about your comments. The original poster does not indicate Ethernet anywhere.

Comment: From OP   ......   And yes, I do have Ethernet access

Comment: If the bulbs support this, the connection method will be documented and you'll be able to find it. If they require some sort of open network, that will be documented as well. You need to tell us the model of the bulbs and you should probably start by reading the bulb docs to see what they say about this.

Comment: “And yes, I do have Ethernet access…” Can you please explain what this means? Do you have access to the same public Internet via Wi-Fi as well as Ethernet? Your question is vague and seems to be only a Wi-Fi question without those details.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, yes, you can do this.

As you have Ethernet, the solution is to set up your own router (ie with its own SSID = Access point name) and connect the WAN port to the Ethernet and your the devices to your routers SSID [ SSID=WIFI name ].

(If you did not have an ethernet connection you could still do this with a bit of hackery - either by having 2 back-to-back devices - one configured as an AP which your IOT devices could connect to and the other configured as an AP client to speak to your actual AP.    There are also all-in-one devices which can do this for you - generally described as "travel routers")

You do need to be a bit careful here - you will want to make sure you use a different WIFI channel for your router/AP to the one used by your Internet provider - and this can be quite challenging.  (On the 2.4 gig network there are typically only 3 non overlapping channels - 1, 6 and 11).  If you have an Android phone you can use the "WIFI Analyser" app to show the use of channels including the width of each channel.      If you can't use a non-overlapping channel, any channel will work, but will slow down WIFI for everyone when you are transmitting/receiving (likely not a big deal with IOT devices as they use very little bandwidth).

If you can use the 5 gig band, this will have a smaller range, but not interfere with other users as much, and having many more non-overlapping channels.  Unfortunately I think many/most IOT devices are still 2.4 gig band (because the common ESP8266 and ESP32 chips they use for WIFI functionality are 2.4 gig only)

You may also be able to reach out to your WIFI provider and provide them with a list of MAC addresses [ ie the WIFI addresses of your IOT devices ] and have them whitelist these.   Of-course, that means every time you have a new device you need to get your provider to update them.